# ClosedXml Excel Add multiple values to Rows

Tags: c#

Trying to add values from an array `string[]` to a row in Excel.
When I'm trying to use `dt.Rows.Add(string[i])` it is added to the Excel sheet. The problem is it is added vertically, which is quite obvious because I'm only adding one item to the row and then insert a new row. My question now is how to add every item from the `string[]` to one row so that my data is displayed horizontally.

For example `string[] values = {"a","b","c","d"};`
The output I have at the moment:
a
b
c
d

The output I want:
a b c d (each in a different cell).

A1 = a
B1 = b
...

I've already been able to add columns to the worksheet, I only need my data to be right.
This is my code for now.

```
//Add columns
dt.Columns.AddRange(columns.Select(c => new DataColumn(c.ToString())).ToArray());
List<string> temp;
string[] values;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    temp = new List<string>();
    temp.Add(timeStamps[i].ToString());
    foreach (var item in tagCollection)
    {
        if (timeStamps[i].Date == item.time)
        {
            temp.Add(item.min);
            temp.Add(item.max);
            temp.Add(item.avg);
        }    
    }
    int index = 0;
    values = new string[temp.Count];
        
    foreach (var item in temp)
    {
        values[index] = item;
        dt.Rows.Add(values[index]);
        index++;
    }
}

//Convert datatable to dataset and add it to the workbook as worksheet
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
workbook.Worksheets.Add(ds);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution may go through the following:

```
 string[] cars = { "Volvo", "BMW", "Mazda" };
 table.Rows.Add(cars[0].ToString(), cars[1].ToString(), cars[2].ToString());
```

Output:

[image]

Just need to adapt to your own code.

You've to guarantee that your Datasheet has the columns needed to display all data in the same row. If you didn't do that, for sure it will generate a matrix error.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I Changed the `foreach` loop and discoverd that there was a `NewRow()` method.

```
int index = 0;
values = new string[temp.Count];
DataRow newRow;
newRow = dt.NewRow();

foreach (var item in temp) {
    values[index] = item;
    newRow.ItemArray = temp.Cast<object>().ToArray();
    index++;
}
dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
```